# Google Forms Fail To Unlink from Sheet (Broken)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

hope someone can assist with this one.

We have created an app for a clients that creates pre-populated Google Forms linked back to a common spreadsheet with other sheets linked to forms.  As the Form are completed the script locates the corresponding Forms, opens the Form and unlinks the Form from the spreadsheet.  Then the sheet for the unlinked Form is removed from the spreadsheet

99% of the time this works as expected however at times the sheet can not be delete and the Form can not be unlinked removed by code or manually.

We also get sheets with a conflict message appended to the sheet name.  Eg this is the 12,454th Form created and linked to the spreadsheet and the sheet name is "Form responses 12454_conflict1685393126" when it should be "Form responses 12454"  These Forms also can not be Unlinked.

Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

Comment: If you can provide a specific error message, and a line of code that produces that error, it's more likely that you'll get an answer.  If there is no error, then provide the line of code that removes the spreadsheet.  You did describe the expected result versus what happens.  That's the easy part.  If this is a bug that needs to be fixed, you would need to provide a way for Google to reproduce the error.  Because this works most of the time, it will be very difficult to consistently reproduce the issue.  There *are* quota limits that sometimes cause inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check on this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/5NC2h-q7snQ). It suggested to do some workarounds which might help:

- Clear your [cookies & cache](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/95582?hl=en-GB)
- Try [Incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)/[private window](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fprivate-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH5YTK-xMxBa1T3e2zbtbk-KMA4Ew)
- Disable [extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en)/[add-ons](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fdisable-or-remove-add-ons&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGd7cm5vfVHX9C4-Ur9LViGVCN_jw)/[plug-ins](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142064?hl=en).

  - Disable all extensions by doing a browser reset.
  - Here's a link to the Google Support Center for how to do that: [Chrome Browser Reset](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).
- Try a different browser to see if it is a browser related issue
- Make sure you are using the most current OS for your device. Here is a link to [the operating systems Chrome supports](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en).
- Make sure you're using the latest version of Chrome.
- [Reset](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?vid=null&vid=null) your Chrome settings
- Run [Chrome Cleanup Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/), to remove software that may cause Chrome to experience issues.

This [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/WoG704snRYU) might also help.

Comment: Hi @abielita and others.  The issue has been cleared as browser related.  The issue happens about 1 in 1000 which is every few days.  In a year, the Spreadsheet generates around 100,000 pre populated forms and collected responses.  About 100 sheets can not be unlinked from the Spreadsheet during a year and at that stage the Spreadsheet fails due to capacity limits.  The code processes PDF creation, sending email and other function as expected but the unlinking remains a problem at times.